# html css not going well

Tags: css

Am I typing something in wrong for the background image not to be working? All the folders and files are in the correct spot for it to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>First Project</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.folder/first_project.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>marvelous day</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
h1 {
    color: blue;
}

body {
    background-image: url("img/pattern.png");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your folder structure is the following

- css

  - first_project.css
- img

  - pattern.png
- index.html

if this is the case in your css you should add **../** before your url so that the browser can know where the image is located

```
body{
    background-image:url("../img/pattern.png");
}
```

pay attention for relative urls in your css

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot. Going to sound like a noob but what exactly does the ".." mean at the beginning of that url? I was taught a whole different way.

Comment: that's great, the "../" tells the browser when it's reading the code to go back one level and then enter in img folder

Comment: ahhh got it... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a slash at the beginning so it starts looking from the root:

```
background-image: url("/img/pattern.png");
```